# Are math-heavy cosmology questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

Recently I have asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058886/how-to-solve-equation-of-motion-of-cosmological-scalar-field) related to cosmology. I discovered that there is no [cosmology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology) tag. Are cosmology questions which are heavily math-based on-topic?

Comment: The ODE tag you've applied already looks good to me, and the question is entirely mathematical so it's on topic.  You might add a little more context to it though -- it would be worth indicating what level of mathematical knowledge you have so that answerers can pitch their answers better.  Maybe add in where you would start looking for a solution, such as by calculating $V\prime$ yourself, and you should definitely indicate where $R$ comes from

Comment: Thank you. Yes, these are good points, about to implement them...

Comment: I have added the mathematical physics tag.

Comment: Just fyi if you happen to edit your question, a side effect will be that it is "bumped" it into the active question queue, which usually results in additional visibility.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As long as it's heavily math-based, it's on topic. Cosmology questions just haven't been posted frequently enough to warrant a tag for them. [mathematical-physics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics) should suffice.